# Auto Update a LastDateModified Field on save of a record

Tags: ms-access

I am working on an access frontend and an MSSql backend.  I am using a button attached to an event macro that will "save" the record.  I would like this button to also update the lastdatemodified field with the current date.  I would also be willing to modify this to use vba if that is required.

I have tried several of the solutions that I have seen on the internet, but none of them seem to work.

There are no errors, but it does not update the table.

Comment: Edit question to post attempted code. Are you using SetValue? I use only VBA.

Comment: I have tried it with SetValue.  still no joy with it and again I am find with re-writing the button to use VBA to update the information so long as it is pretty straight forward.  The design is simple and there is not a lot going on with it so there does not really need to be a whole lot of checks for it.  There currently is no code in this as up to this point it has all been done with the embedded macros options inside of access.

Comment: As I said, post your code for analysis. VBA works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your form is bound to a linked SQL Server table, you can use the form BeforeUpdate event.  This will set the lastmodifieddate field just before the data is saved to SQL Server.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
     [lastmodifieddate] = Now
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I was trying it on the field on the form rather than the form itself.